# Active Directory Search to get users domain

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap, vb.net-2010

I am trying to query Active directory for a user to get a list of details:
1. First/Last Name
2. Email
3. UserName
4. Domain

I am able to get all except for the domain name. Here is my code:

```
    Dim oroot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("GC://ldap.someCompany.com")
    Dim osearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oroot)
    Dim result As SearchResult

    osearcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", "myUsername")
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName")   'Users login name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")    'Users first name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")   'Users sur name  
    osearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")   'Email address

    result = osearcher.FindOne

    Try
        myUser.UserID = result.Properties("cn").Item(0)
        myUser.Domain = ""
        myUser.EmailAddress = result.Properties("mail").Item(0)
        myUser.FirstName = result.Properties("givenName").Item(0)
        myUser.LastName = result.Properties("sn").Item(0)
        myUser.Domain = result.Properties("displayName").Item(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
```

This returns this string: GC://ldap.someCompany.com/CN=FirstName M LastName,OU=Employees,OU=Domain Users,DC=val1,DC=val2,DC=com

So, I have two questions. First, how do I get the domain name of the user? It appears to be in DC= (where I have val1)
Second, is there anyway to speed this search up? Right now, it takes about 10 seconds to run the query.

I am using .net 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010
Thanks for any help

jason

Comment: Attention, `sAMAccountName` is not unique in the forest (in a domain only) so you might get false data. Restrain your search to domain.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What if we have multiple domains? I don't want to filter by domain because when I search for a user, I wont know what their domain is at the time

Comment: It's fine to operate on the GC from RootRSE but you **must** switch to userPrincipalName them. Either implicit or explicit, depending on your AD setup. Say receive `michael-o@STACKOVERFLOW.COM` from your Kerberos service ticket, the you search for `userPrincipalName=michael-o@STACKOVERFLOW.COM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strart from right and read the DC components, then you have the realm/domain of the account. See [RFC2247](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2247.txt).

Comment: So, there's not method (or property) that returns the domain?  I just have to parse the response string?

Comment: You have to process the `distinguishedName`. You actually do not need to do it yourself. There must be some class in .NET like [`LdapName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/LdapName.html) in Java. Then you can easily iterate over all RDNs.